# How do I scrape values from a file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, flowtype

[*This question is about how to complete this task in Visual Studio Code, but if there's a `React`/`Flow` tool/technique that'd do the trick, please do share*]

I have several `React` component files (`.js`/`.jsx`) that use numerous `props` throughout. For example, one file might contain:

```
this.props.handleClick
this.props.isOpen
this.props.totalTags
// etc etc etc
```

...each spread throughout the file.

I'd like to create some kind of macro or shortcut that, upon execution, would parse the file for all unique instances of `this.props.*`, and create a snippet at the top of the file similar to:

```
type Props = {
  /** description of handleClick prop*/
  handleClick: <type>,

  /** description of isOpen prop*/
  isOpen: <type>,

  /** description of totalTags prop*/
  totalTags: <type>
}
```

I know how to make a `snippet` that'd put the boilerplate in for me, but I'd like to know if it's feasible to automate the scraping of the file portion of this task as well.

Ideally, I could avoid using an external tool (`gulp`, et al), but if that's the only way, I'd love to hear about it.